# How to link azure application insights to aks

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-aks

App services have a good integration with application insights. Request can be traced from the caller through the dependencies across service boundaries.
This is not available by default with AKS.
I am trying to use this lab .
https://azure.github.io/kube-labs/5-aks-appinsights.html#objective-of-the-lab
Although when I reach the third step which is to execute init.sh,it gives me error.
ERROR: After approving csr app-monitoring-webhook.kube-system, the signed certificate did not appear on the resource. Giving up after 10 attempts.

I have modified the init.sh.
Changed apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1 from v1beta1.
Used this link: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/certificate-signing-requests/#kubernetes-signers
[image]

Still getting this error.Is there any other way to link app insights with aks?
I am doing this for a .net core project.

Answer (score 1):

[I'm from Application Insights team]

We're actively investing into providing similar experience for AKS as we do for App Services (glad that the latter is working for you!). Unfortunately, above lab is a few years old and based on private preview bits. We'll try to update this lab.

One option which is available today (and many AKS customers use it) is to instrument with Application Insights .NET SDK. Essentially you'll get exactly the same experience as with App Services (all incoming/outgoing requests will be auto-discovered and collected).

Comment: Thank you.Are you referring to this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/kubernetes-codeless. Will this approach give me end to end tracing insights also?

Comment: Which language are you using? Java?

Comment: No. C#. ASP.NET Core

Comment: Then I'd recommend to follow this link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core?tabs=netcorenew%2Cnetcore6). It was under .NET Core from your link. The option is to follow Visual Studio path. Yes, end-to-end tracing will be supported

Comment: By when will the lab be updated if I want to use codeless attach method?

Comment: The lab will be updated by removing this lab :) We're working on a private preview but unfortunately I cannot share ETA. And it will definitely be some time till Public Preview and finally till GA.